# Authentication in REST node js server, using an Android client with Facebook login

Tags: android, node.js, facebook, express

In my android app I have a facebook login which gives me an access token and profile ID, however I do not understand how to use them to authenticate in my node js REST server. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are several ways to authenticate :

option 1 :

> Send Fb id to node js server where it checks in db that if the user
>   already exists then generate **jwt** token in return ,else create a
>   new user by its fb id and return a **jwt** token and save this token
>   on client side to authenticate every request in headers.

option 2 :

> this will be a secure one , pass fb id and token both to the node js server,
>   first authenticate the fb-token directly with the facebook API then
>   perform the same functionality as in option 1.

Comment: Thanks. I found that the second option is exactly what FB recommends.